# updating value in junction table is troublesome spring data JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two Entities one as

```
@Entity    
public class Job {  

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Size(min = 5,max = 50, message = "Valid title is 5-50 chars")
    private String title;       

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "jobs_categories",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "jobs_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id"))
    private List<Category> categories;
    // omitting setters/getters
}
```

and other as

```
@Entity
public class Category {    

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Size(min = 5,max = 15, message = "Valid name is 5-15 chars")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}) 
    private List<Job> jobs; 
    // omitting setters/getters
    }
```

I want to implement **CRUD** operations on those two, 
I save one job with some categories as

```
Job title - Fullstack JavaScript CSS3 / HTML5 / Developer
Categories - AngularJS, Backbone.js, CSS, CSS3, Graphic design, HTML, HTML5,
             JavaScript, MongoDB Node.js, twitter bootstrap, Web design.
```

then if I want to update the job by adding or removing categories from above saved Job, it is never updating (e.g, adding/removing) categories.

for updating Job I have method in JobService as

```
@Service
public class JobService{

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;

    private Session session;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobService.class);      

    public void updateJobCategory(Job job) {                
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.getObject().createEntityManager();
    session= entityManager.unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class);
    logger.info("got Job ID as  ==> " + String.valueOf(job.getId()));
    Job jobObj = (Job) session.get(Job.class, job.getId());
    jobObj.getCategories().clear();     
    logger.info("got Job ID as  ==> " + String.valueOf(jobObj.getId()));

    if (!job.getCategories().isEmpty()) {
        logger.info("got job.getCategories() as not Null");
        List<Category> categories = job.getCategories();
        for (Category category : categories) {              
            logger.info("Good job.getCategories() to update ==> " + category.getName());
        }
        logger.info("adding job.getCategories() to update ==> ");
        jobObj.setCategories(job.getCategories());      

    }else {
        logger.info("got job.getCategories() as Null");
    }
    session.update(jobObj); 

    }
    public void update(Job job) {
        jobRepository.update(job.getId(), job.getTitle());
        updateJobCategory(job);
    }
}
```

I get log

```
logger.info("Got job.getCategories() to update" + category.getName());
```

I'm getting updated (new added/old removed) list of all categories,

```
Hibernate: update job set title=? where id=?
INFO : com.rhcloud.jobsnetwork.service.JobService - got Job ID as  ==> 1
Hibernate: select job0_.id as id1_1_0_, job0_.title as title7_1_0_ from job job0_ where job0_.id=?
Hibernate: select categories0_.jobs_id as jobs_id1_1_0_, categories0_.categories_id as categori2_2_0_, category1_.id as id1_0_1_, category1_.name as name2_0_1_ from jobs_categories categories0_ inner join category category1_ on categories0_.categories_id=category1_.id where categories0_.jobs_id=?
INFO : com.rhcloud.jobsnetwork.service.JobService - got Job ID as  ==> 1
INFO : com.rhcloud.jobsnetwork.service.JobService - got job.getCategories() as not Null
INFO : com.rhcloud.jobsnetwork.service.JobService - Good job.getCategories() to update ==> iOS App Dev
INFO : com.rhcloud.jobsnetwork.service.JobService - Good job.getCategories() to update ==> Android App Dev
INFO : com.rhcloud.jobsnetwork.service.JobService - adding job.getCategories() to update
```

but when I see details of Job I get the categories listed which were added on the creation of job not updated ones, I guess it is not updating categories id values in  junction table `jobs_categories`.
No idea of Updating categories related to job?

**UPDATE**

When I use

```
public void persistJob(Job newJob) {
         em.persist(newJob);
       }

       public void saveJob(Job job) {
          em.merge(job);
       }
       public void persistCategory(Category newcat) {
         em.persist(newcat);
       }
```

without `@Transactional` at every method I get expception

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:275)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy167.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.rhcloud.jobsnetwork.service.JobService.persistJob(JobService.java:29)
    at com.rhcloud.jobsnetwork.service.JobService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$53974ce3.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649)
    at com.rhcloud.jobsnetwork.service.JobService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c08e8d16.persistJob(<generated>)
    at com.rhcloud.jobsnetwork.controllers.JobController.addJobDetail(JobController.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

After adding `@Transactional` it works got rid of above exception, I save new job using

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-job", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addJobDetail(@ModelAttribute("job") Job job) {            
        jobService.persistJob(job); 
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

I get all the things working perfect, but when I use `saveJob` in JobController as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updated", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateJob(@ModelAttribute("job") Job job) {           
        jobService.saveJob(job);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

there is no any category(no earlier added no updated ones) saved in updated job, any suggestions in this case.

### Update - 2

As per your suggestion I added logger to

```
 @Transactional
   public void saveJob(Job job) {
       logger.error("got job.getCategories() of " + job.getCategories().size());
      em.merge(job);         
   }
```

at this point I get NullPointerException at

```
 logger.error("got job.getCategories() of " + job.getCategories().size() + " size");
```

log/trace is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.rhcloud.jobsnetwork.service.JobService.saveJob(JobService.java:37)
    at com.rhcloud.jobsnetwork.service.JobService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$53974ce3.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.rhcloud.jobsnetwork.service.JobService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$41dc2ac2.saveJob(<generated>)
    at com.rhcloud.jobsnetwork.controllers.JobController.updateJob(JobController.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: what is the use of the var : categoryObj ? is 'job' also in the session (has it been loaded or saved before calling this updateJobCategory method) ?

Comment: var : categoryObj is just for logging, it may be removed.

Comment: @Thierry Please have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you have two entities, that can each exist on their own - category is fine without a job, and a job can have no categories assigned. `orphanRemoval` is used in `OnetoMany` or `OneToOne`, if you would like to perform a delete operation on the related entity that is no longer referenced from the parent entity(think composition), which isn't the case here. I believe you merely want to remove the link between the job and a the particular Category(think association).

You mapping is correct (bidirectional manytomany with Job as the relationship owner), I would suggest only minor modifications:
Use `java.util.Set`(improve performance with delete on join table, prevent 'can not fetch multiple bags' exception) for you collections and override `equals` method(to make collection operations easier).

Here we go:

```
@Entity    
public class Job { 
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String title;

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinTable(name = "jobs_categories", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "jobs_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id") )
private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>();
```

And Category

```
@Entity
public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
private List<Job> jobs;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Category other = (Category) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

One of the issues in your update function is that you override a reference to the collection in the Job entity.

`jobObj.setCategories(job.getCategories());`

You should always modify the original collection, never assign a new collection.

You might also consider removing the `Merge` cascade altogether from your `ManyToMany` as it will make the code workflow easier to understand - categories will be managed separately and you only add already saved categories to the new Job instance(but this is just a suggestion, we will make it work even with the cascade :) ).

Now for some test code. I am using plain JPA, not Spring repositories, to make it simple to understand.

JobService(in your case it will be split into multiple classes, repositories..):

```
public class JobService {

   @PersistenceContext
   EntityManager em;

   public void persistJob(Job newJob) {
     em.persist(newJob);
   }

   public Job getJob(Integer jobId) {
     return em.find(Job.class, jobId);
   }

   public void saveJob(Job job) {
      em.merge(job);
   }

   public void persistCategory(Category newcat) {
     em.persist(newcat);
   }

   public List<Category> getAllCategories() {
     return em.createQuery("from Category", Category.class).getResultList();
   }  
}
```

And lets test it:

```
Job job = new Job();
job.setTitle("Web developer");
Category catJS = new Category();
catJS.setName("javascript");
Category catCSS = new Category();
catCSS.setName("CSS");
Category catNG = new Category();
catNG.setName("AngualrJS");
Category catHTML = new Category();
catHTML.setName("HTML5");
//persist categories separately
jobservice.persistCategory(catNG);
jobservice.persistCategory(catCSS);
jobservice.persistCategory(catHTML);
jobservice.persistCategory(catJS);
//at this point, we have 4 categories as managed entities
//add the saved categories to a new job instance
job.getCategories().add(catHTML);
job.getCategories().add(catJS);

//save job in DB
jobservice.persistJob(job);
//we do not need to set Job references in Category objects, because Job is the relationship owner - it will correctly update the FKs in join table
assertNotNull("job should be saved", job.getId());
Job fromDb = jobservice.getJob(job.getId());//reload from DB
assertNotNull("job should be stored in DB", fromDb);
assertTrue("job should have 2 categories", fromDb.getCategories().size() == 2);
//great si far so good  

//remove one of the assigned categories from Job(this is where you need that **equals** method in Category )
fromDb.getCategories().remove(catHTML);
assertTrue("job should not have only one category in Memory", fromDb.getCategories().size() ==1);
jobservice.saveJob(fromDb);
//we do not want to delete the *HTML* category from DB, just remove it from the particular job
Job fromDbAfterUpdate = jobservice.getJob(job.getId());
assertTrue("job should not have only one category in BD", fromDbAfterUpdate.getCategories().size() ==1);
List<Category> allCategories = jobservice.getAllCategories();
assertTrue("there should still be 4 categories in DB", allCategories.size() == 4);


//now lets test the Merge cascade
Category unsavedCategory = new Category();
unsavedCategory.setName("jquery");
fromDbAfterUpdate.getCategories().add(unsavedCategory );
//we have added an unsaved category to an  existing job. As Job has cascade merge on it categories, the *unsavedCategory* will be saved and then linked to job via job_category join table
jobservice.saveJob(fromDbAfterUpdate);
fromDbAfterUpdate = jobservice.getJob(fromDbAfterUpdate.getId());
assertTrue("job should now have 2 categories", fromDbAfterUpdate.getCategories().size() ==2);


// one more test, add and remove at the same time
fromDbAfterUpdate.getCategories().remove(catJS);
fromDbAfterUpdate.getCategories().add(catHTML);
fromDbAfterUpdate.getCategories().add(catCSS);
jobservice.saveJob(fromDbAfterUpdate);
fromDbAfterUpdate = jobservice.getJob(fromDbAfterUpdate.getId());
assertTrue("job should now have 3 categories", fromDbAfterUpdate.getCategories().size() ==3);
allCategories = jobservice.getAllCategories();
assertTrue("there should be 5 categories in DB", allCategories.size() == 5);
```

TL;DR

- Keep your update method simple - you do not need to fetch the object from DB and move things between managed and detached object, let JPA merge do its thing
- Never change a reference to a collection of managed entities - perform operations directly on the collection
- Omit any cascades until you really need them

For more info, please consult [JPA Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html)

Comment: Thank for your kind consideration, but how can I _update_ __job__ with edited values__(e.g update name, categories)__ can you provide a _method_ for that purpose as there are methods _save_ or _getAllCategories_ please it'll be very very nice of you :|

Comment: update in JPA terms is `merge`. The example `JobService` has two methods for saving Jobs - `persistJob` - only for new jobs - will result in `INSERT` statement. the other method - `saveJob` does `em.merge` and will result in SQL `UPDATE`. Therefore if you change any job attribute it will be saved when you call `em.merge(job)`. The test code provided first saves a job with two categories and then performs several changes on that job's categories

Comment: could you debug/add logging before you call ` jobService.saveJob(job);` to see if there are any categories in that job instance at that time? As you are doing `HTTP POST` can you verify that the Job is being sent along with its categories? You have to keep in mind, that the JOb object you get in your REST method is not a managed entity - it is a completely detached entity deseriliazed from HTTP POST. Also check whether the ID of that object matches the ID of the Job instance you persisted earlier.

Comment: Please see my __Update-2__ in my Question above.

Comment: ok, the null pointer is clearly caused by the fact that your Job instance has no categories at the time you pass it to `em.merge` i.e. `job.getCategories()` is null. How do you call your REST method? can you verify that the object, that you sent in your POST request, contains the categories. This issue has nothing to do with JPA it is simply caused by the fact, that that particular instance has no categories assigned. Create a test method, where you test the JPA related functionality to verify that the update works there. Then analyze your REST to identify, why the categories get lost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94408/discussion-between-yntelectual-and-arshad-ali).

Comment: Ooops there were some JS issue which were not adding data to `job.getCategories()`, I resolved it now it works like charm. it is very very very very very...!!! Nice of you that you helped me in that case. one last thing I wanna ask if you don't mind, that is __is there any way to get things working like this using JPA repositories__ please!

Comment: Waiting for your comment regarding my last comment please??

Comment: glad it works for you. Repositories are a Spring framew. concept, nothing to do with JPA. They abstract common DAO functionality in Spring, so there is no reason why it would not work. For example if you had a `JobRepository` you could use `jobRepo.save(job)` instead of `em.persist` and `em.merge` just bear in mind that `jobRepo.save` returns the managed ref, so you have to assign it back to the instance you work on e.g. `myJob = jobRepo.save(myJob)`.  So just replace your current `jobService.persist` and `jobService.save` with `repo.save`. Querying should be trivial to replace. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

You have wrong mapping.
Try this:

```
@Entity
public class Category {    

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@Size(min = 5,max = 15, message = "Valid name is 5-15 chars")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true) 
@JoinColumn(name = "jobs_id",referencedColumnName = "jobs_id")
private List<Job> jobs; 
// omitting setters/getters
}
```

and second entity:

```
@Entity    
public class Job {  

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@Size(min = 5,max = 50, message = "Valid title is 5-50 chars")
private String title;       

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "categories_id",referencedColumnName = "categories_id")
private List<Category> categories;
// omitting setters/getters
}
```

P.s. edit column names as in table;

Comment: Thanks for your kind consideration, but your answer isn't working. first it say's _The attribute orphanRemoval is undefined for the annotation type ManyToMany_, then it creates 4 tables instead of three. means to say I want __job__, __category__ and __jobs_categories__, but it creates __job__, __category__ , __jobs_categories__  and __categories_jobs__ Sorry!!

Comment: one of the entities needs to be the owner of the relationship, see chapter 2.9 _The inverse side of a bidirectional relationship must refer to its owning side by use of the
mappedBy element of the OneToOne, OneToMany, or ManyToMany annotation._ and default mappings applied in chapter 2.10.4 of [JPA spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html)